# Удалить источник из существующего графа - фильтра ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Пусть есть уже граф микширования. Добавляются в него новые источники легко, а вот как удалить отдельный источник из него? Придумал пока только обнулять граф с помощью `avfilter_graph_free`, а потом создавать его заново из оставшихся источников. Но так делать не хотельсь бы из-за "заторможения" работы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void avfilter_free(AVFilterContext *filter)` не помог?

> Free a filter context.
>
> **This will also remove the filter from its filtergraph's list of filters.**

https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.4/group__lavfi.html#ga0ea7664a3ce6bb677a830698d358a179

Comment: А, что-то я его не увидел в описании. Сейчас попробую.
Тут возникла проблема с некорректной работой функции перед очисткой графа. придется ее сначала исправить перед проверкой `void avfilter_free(AVFilterContext *filter)`